# aws-sdk use only needed package e.g. couldwatchlog and config (with credentials)

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I want to use the cloudwatchlog client from **AWS SDK** (JS) and also set the credentials. So that I am not including the whole AWS SDK bundle inside my Application, because it is very large and slows down the page. Is there a way to configure the credentials and then only use the needed client from the AWS SDK?

so far I have tried this but it doesn't work with the config, typescript says the update method doesn't exist on Config:

```
import {Config} from 'aws-sdk/lib/core'; 
import {CloudWatchLogs} from 'aws-sdk';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily I have just done this the other day to shrink down my bundle size as well.
First I would recommend getting the correct `aws-sdk config` library with:

```
let Config = require('aws-sdk/global');
```

To get just the individual `CloudWatchLogs` you would need to get it like so:

```
let CloudWatchLogs = require('aws-sdk/clients/cloudwatchlogs');
```

After this you can configure the credentials like you would before, and to get a new `CloudWatchLog` you can do: `let cloudwatch = new CloudWatchLogs()`

Hopefully this helps some.

Comment: thank you very much, yes that also worked. But I now found a different solution as well, I pass the credentials to the CloudWatchLogs constructor which seem to work as well. No need for the extra Config import!

Comment: @Daniel Yes you technically don't need to require the ```aws-sdk/global``` because the individual clients can access the config themselves.  Glad I could help!  The ```aws-sdk``` can bog up your bundle file very quickly.

Comment: Will it work if I import `config` as `import { config as AWSConfig } from 'aws-sdk/global'`? Then, I can use `AWSConfig.credentials`, for example.